# How do I return the two lowest values in Python Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, min

I need to find the two smallest values in my dictionary. I cannot use lambda. I could use lists, min().

I cannot use any functions outside of min(). I could use .sort on a list though, but that would mean converting my dictionary values to a list. How do I do that?

Comment: Please see the [intro tour,](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the [help center,](https://stackoverflow.com/help) this post on [how to ask a good question,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hint:  `dict.values()`

Comment: Thanks. I did min(dict.values()) but it only printed the first min value. I need the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you need only the first 2 min values.

```
>>> dict = {'A' : 11, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 11, 'D':8, 'E':1}
>>> sorted(dict.values())[:2]
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Try this if you need the first 2 min values along with its keys.

```
>>> sorted(dict.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])[:2]
[('E', 1), ('B', 2)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try this code and it will help you to return keys with minimum values

```
    test_dict = {'A' : 11, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 11, 'D':8, 'E':2} 

    # printing original dictionary 

    print("The original dictionary is : " + str(test_dict))

    # Using min() + list comprehension + values() 

    temp = min(test_dict.values()) 
    res = [key for key in test_dict if test_dict[key] == temp] 

    # printing result  

    print("Keys with minimum values are : " + str(res))
```